# Animations broken in jQuery 1.6!

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I upgraded to jQuery 1.6 this morning and now a lot of the animations I spent so long fine tuning in my app are now failing. Here is an example of one. Notice how the 1.5 animation keeps the box centered, but on the 1.6 animation the something goes wrong.

I have narrowed it down to something to do with the opacity being involved in the animation. If I remove the opacity it works fine...

**Example with JQ 1.5:** http://jsfiddle.net/LJZ54/3/

**Example with JQ 1.6:** http://jsfiddle.net/LJZ54/4/

**Example with JQ 1.6 (no opacity):** http://jsfiddle.net/LJZ54/5/

Question: How should I alter my animation code to work in the new jQuery 1.6?

Comment: Did you read the breaking changes list ? http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

Comment: I don't see it stating anything about animation in the breaking changes...

Comment: All them fiddles work for me...Tested in IE8, FF and Chrome.

Comment: @anothershrubery you should notice the 1.6 example does not stay centered.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: The second example is clearly different to the first for me, the first is smooth and centered

Comment: No when I use the same version of Chrome it looks exactly the same as the 1.5 version.

Comment: I can confirm on chrome 10, the 1.5 version animated from the centre of the square, while in 1.6 the origin is the top left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited one of your jsFiddles to work with the new 1.6 changes.

Seems ok to me now: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/RULJN/

On your `marginLeft` and `marginTop` I changed the values from `marginLeft:-200` to `marginLeft:"-200px"`.

They need to be in quotes to work. Same for `width` and `height`.

To make the animations work I changed the following:

```
$('div').animate({
    width:400,
    height: 400,
    marginLeft: -200,
    marginTop: -200,
    opacity:1
},500);
```

To:

```
$('div').animate({
    width:"400px",
    height: "400px",
    marginLeft: "-200px",
    marginTop:"-200px",
    opacity:1
},500);
```

Putting the dimension in quotes makes the animation work. I have a feeling they should of been in quotes anyway.

Comment: It this example does not match the 1.5 example I posted (http://jsfiddle.net/LJZ54/3/). Your animation seems to grow from the bottom right hand corner. The intention is for the square to grow from the center.

Comment: Sorry yes. Just views all the others again. Its possible it may be a bug then.

Comment: I've just something similar if you view http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/RULJN/ again.

Comment: @Tomgrohl Brilliant! If you post that as an answer I will confirm.